# JSTileMap tileGidAtCoord not responding with all GIDs?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, jstilemap

I am trying to find other child nodes within the same GID, essentially find my neighbor nodes. However, in my 25x25 map I only retrieve 4 GIDs for some reason, 6, 7, 19, and 20.  My understanding is that there should be 625 GIDs, one for each tile, - but maybe I do not understand Tile Maps that well.  When I load the view I see the map and the players fine, randomly positioned around as I would want.

I am using a 25x25 tile map, 16x16 pixels each tile, and I randomly add player nodes to a JSTileMap between 0 and 400 for x and y. My map has one layer.

```
agent.player.position = CGPointMake(agent.xPos.floatValue, agent.yPos.floatValue);
agent.player.zPosition = 15;
[self.map addChild:agent.player];
```

Then I convert the position to a JSTileMap point, because I understand it inverts the y axis.

```
TMXLayer *layer = self.ground;
CGPoint playerCoord = [layer coordForPoint:agent.player.position];
```

Then I want to retrieve the GID for this player and store it in a dictionary so I can later find out who all the neighbors are.

```
TMXLayerInfo *layerInfo = layer.layerInfo;
NSInteger currentTileGID = [layerInfo tileGidAtCoord:playerCoord];
```

Interestingly currentTileGID only has values of 6, 7, 19, or 20, despite what I would think would be random GIDs between 1 and 625.  What I am not understanding about this behavior?  The input playerCoord values seem correct as random from 0 to 400 for both x and y.

Thank you,
lta

Comment: I have solved this issue.  I did not understand how GIDs worked.  I thought this was a global ID for the map, when it is a global ID for each layer and its set of possible tiles.  I was using tiles 6, 7, 19, and 20 from the desert tile set I downloaded.  This tutorial helped me: <http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/parsing-tiled-tmx-format-maps-in-your-own-game-engine--gamedev-3104>

I still do not know if JSTileMap has a GID for the base map, that would be very useful, but I think i must write my own code to determine positions.

-Lta

Comment: GIDs represent individual tiles and are unique across the map, over tile sets.  0 represents "no tile".  It sounds like you are more interested in getting the actual sprites rather than using the GIDs.